# Bluetooth help with Arduino Due

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, arduino-due

I have been able to establish a successful connection between an RN-42 Bluetooth module and Arduino Uno, but I could not do the same with an Arduino Due. The module connects to the phone but whatever data I send is not registered. What is different on the Due in the context of Bluetooth connectivity? Baud-rate perhaps?

Comment: do you use hardwareserial or softserial? are you sure that you hooked up the rx tx as well as pwr and gnd correctly?

Comment: Please show your code and explain which pins the Bluetooth is connected to on both boards?

Comment: int ledPin = 13; 
int state = 0;
int flag = 0; 
 
void setup() {
 pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
 
 Serial1.begin(115200); // Default connection rate for my BT module
}
 
void loop() {

 if(Serial.available() > 0){
 state = Serial.read();
 flag=0;
 }

 if (state == '0') {
 digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
 if(flag == 0){
 Serial.println("LED: off");
 flag = 1;
 }
 }
 else if (state == '1') {
 digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
 if(flag == 0){
 Serial.println("LED: on");
 flag = 1;
 }
 }
}

Comment: The pins are:                                                                                                   5v(RN-42) -->  5v (Arduino due),                                                                       GND(RN-42) --> GND(Arduino due),                                                       RX(RN-42) --> TX(Arduino due),                                                                   TX(RN-42) --> RX(Arduino due),                                                                      these are the project details @VisualMicro

Comment: Lastly, when I had 9600 as my baud rate in the code it didn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code and additional details there, not in the comments.